# create a button for change the font

Tags: android, button

i wrote this code to create a button for changing font but i isn't work and if condition never became true what is my problem?

```
font.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Typeface mitra = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/MitraB.ttf");

            if (WBC.getTypeface() == mitra) {

                Typeface tabssom = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/tabassom.ttf");
                WBC.setTypeface(tabssom);
            } else {
                WBC.setTypeface(mitra);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you want to do 'WBC.getTypeface() == mitra' or 'WBC.getTypeface().equals(mitra)'?

Comment: @user2692841 , why are u comparing string literal with == operator instead of equals method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly put MitraB.ttf and tabassom.ttf into asset folder itself and call it like this:

```
font.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Typeface t1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"MitraB.ttf");

        if (WBC.getTypeface().equals(t1))
        {
            Typeface t2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"tabassom.ttf");
            WBC.setTypeface(t2);
        }
        else
        {
            WBC.setTypeface(t1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 font.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Typeface mitra = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "font/MitraB.ttf");
        WBC.setTypeface(mitra); //edit
        if (WBC.getTypeface().equals(mitra)) {
             Typeface tabssom = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "font/tabassom.ttf");
            WBC.setTypeface(tabssom);
        } else {
            WBC.setTypeface(mitra);
        }
    }
});
```

Make sure in your project folder there is a asset folder and within it there is a font folder.

Comment: exactly make sure you have font folder inside assets folder

Comment: fonts are in my asset folder and always the else condition executed I design  it ti be circle but it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
 font.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Typeface mitra = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"font/MitraB.ttf");
        if (WBC.getTypeface().equals(mitra)) {
           Typeface tabssom = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"font/tabassom.ttf");
            WBC.setTypeface(tabssom);
        } else {
            WBC.setTypeface(mitra);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF '**mitra**' is String then compare with equals method not == operator

```
 font.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Typeface mitra = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"font/MitraB.ttf");
            if (WBC.getTypeface().equals(mitra)) {
               Typeface tabssom = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"font/tabassom.ttf");
                WBC.setTypeface(tabssom);
            } else {
                WBC.setTypeface(mitra);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the font, First need to put the font to Asset folder.

Below sample code will show, when click the "Change Font" button, it will change the TextView's font to "KRISTENC.TTF". Please be aware that, font name exactly match with the font name in the asset folder.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="Change Font" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java class

```
package com.font.fonttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnFont = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFont);  
        btnFont.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnFont:

            // Please put the Font KRISTENC.TTF to Assets folder 
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "KRISTENC.TTF");  

            // TextView to show the result
            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            // When click the button change the font type to KRISTENC.TTF
            textView1.setTypeface(font);
        }
    }

}
```